# How to pass an argument from select options to trigger and filter array observables using foreach binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

In the markup below, I am binding unique data containing a list of *Continents*: I am also subscribing to the selected value and triggering an event with the continent selected by the user.

```
<div id="country-collection">
    <select data-bind="options: UniqueContinent,
    value: SelectedContinent"></select>
</div>
```

code:

```
    self.CountryData = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.SelectedContinent = ko.observable('');

    self.UniqueContinent = ko.dependentObservable(function() {
        var continent = ko.utils.arrayMap(self.CountryData(),

            function(item){

                return item.Continent
            })

        return ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(continent).sort();
    });
```

The below function is fired each time a selection is made:

```
    self.SelectedContinent.subscribe(function (selectedValue) {
      // alert(selectedValue);
    });
```

Using the code above, I need to populate the following list with all of the countries based on the default Continent `onload` or a selected Continent: So if Asia is selected, the only countries displayed are countries in Asia and their respective details.

```
<div id="country-list">
    <ul data-bind= "foreach: CountryData">
        <li><span data-bind="text: Country"></span></li>
        // More list stuff here (removed for brevity)
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried this but it only worked if the value is hard coded. I need the Countries to load based on the default value or selected value of the select options:

```
    self.SelectedContinent.subscribe(function (selectedValue) {

        // Call this function when changes are made
        self.FilteredEntries = ko.computed(function() {

            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.CountryData(), function(item) {
                // I need to use the selected value
                return item.Continent === 'SOUTH AMERICA';
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the subscribe function:

```
    // Call this function when changes are made
    self.FilteredEntries = ko.computed(function() {

        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.CountryData(), function(item) {
            // I need to use the selected value
            return item.Continent === self.SelectedContinent();
        });
    });
```

With subscribe you are creating a new computed observable each time the selection changes and the reassigned computed observables are never bound to the DOM.

You can check out the working demo in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yex7dxs2/).

Comment: Thank you! Its working but when I examined the debugger I see this:
`Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.`

Does this require some manual cleanup?

Comment: I don't see any error in the fiddle. The error you encounter - is it in your code or the fiddle I posted ?

Comment: Not the fiddle, the code you posted, I simply did an F12 because I notice the results where showing up sporadically. In Firefox after page load, I see the message under console.

Comment: I am not sure but I am guessing you re-invoked `ko.applyBindings()` on the same page -- that is not valid because ko does not allow you to re-bind to already bound DOM. Can you try updating your code and refreshing the browser.

Comment: This is what my binding looks like:

    `var vm1 = new ExampleApp.CountryCollectionsViewModel;
    var vm2 = new ExampleApp.CountryCollectionsViewModel;

    ko.applyBindings(vm1, document.getElementById('country-collection'));
    ko.applyBindings(vm2, document.getElementById('country-list'));`

Comment: Does the node with id `country-collection` contains the node with id `country-list` or vice versa ?

Comment: No, these are separate divs: `<div id="country-list"></div>` and `<div id="country-collection"></div>`. They are both bind using instances of the same class function/viewmodel. But the data source is the same.

Comment: I am going to accept this as the answer because I do not believe that the issue is related to your solution. I copied your code from the fiddle and could not replicate the same issue. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: If you could try to replicate the problem you are facing in a reproducible fiddle I can try to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the awsome [Knockout Projections](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/12/03/knockout-projections-a-plugin-for-efficient-observable-array-transformations/) plugin, available here; [knockout-projections](https://github.com/stevesanderson/knockout-projections).

Defining the filtered array observable is very simple, and the implementation is highly efficient:

```
var FilteredCountries = self.CountryData().filter(
   function(c) { return c.Continent === self.SelectedContinent(); 
});
```